# Using relative path in file loading dialog of RCPTT

Tags: eclipse-rcptt

In the file dialog i want to load the file from the workspace. For that i need to use the relative path instead of the full path.
Is there anyway to use the relative path(/../workspace/file.txt) instead of full path (D:\codebase\workspace\file.txt).
Because we are running the test from the remote location.

Answer (score 2):

From the ECL Documentation: http://download.xored.com/q7/docs/ecl-api/latest#get-workspace-location.

Use the command "get-workspace-location" to create relative paths. This command will fire back the absolute path of the current workspace the tool is using so you can use it to point to any file that you know the location of relative to the workspace. You can join strings together using the concat command. For example:

set-dialog-result File [concat [get-workspace-location]"/../../test_data/goldenfile01"]